# Changing Chrome Working Directories on Mac clients

Tags: mac-osx, chrome

We're using Mac OSX 10.6.8 with NFS for home directories.  Chrome seems to not like this, for a user who is logged in more than one machine.  AFP was ok, but for other reasons we need NFS.

It only allows you to start one instance.  Ie, userA logged in to Mac1, Mac2.  Can only have chrome open on Mac1 OR mac2, not both.

I have read at this [thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/19323/is-it-feasible-to-have-home-folder-hosted-with-nfs), changing working directory, and sym link can fix... but I can't find the details.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to create a different Chrome profile for each machine.

Look here for instructions on how to start Chrome with a different user data directory: http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory.

You can then set each profile to sync with the same Google Account to sync your bookmarks, etc.